# How can I completely stop a pm2 managed application?

Tags: pm2

Say I have a pm2 process that runs every 5 minutes and takes less than a second to run:

```
pm2 start ./some-node-script.js --name some-node-script --cron "*/5 * * * *" --no-autorestart
```

Now say I want to completely stop execution of the job. If I issue `pm2 stop some-node-script`, I get this warning:

```
[PM2][WARN] App some-node-script stopped but CRON RESTART is still UP */5 * * * *
```

And then the job executes again on the next 5 minute interval. Is there a way I can stop the cron job from executing again? I've tried `pm2 kill`, but that kills every job being managed by pm2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
$ pm2 delete [id]
```

you can retrieve the [id] using

```
$ pm2 ps
```

Comment: or `pm2 delete app_name`

Comment: while i have plus one'd this, i'm curious now that i've deleted it... *how might i put it back* ? under `pm2 help` i don't see a `pm2 add`.  maybe this is a simple question that rtfm would solve, but i'll post my curiosity in case an answer here would add value for others, too.

Comment: You would need to newly start the process / app the same way as you started it in the first place (e. g. using `pm2 start ...`). This usually will assign a new ID (counting up) to the process.

Answer (score 7):

To disable cron restart:

```
pm2 restart app_id --cron-restart 0
```

Then you can just

```
pm2 stop app_id
```

It will save app id.

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/